# get nested element from OnClicks target react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element, materialize, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to change Button's appearance onClick and then will have another button to save the set according to a check and then shipped to database.

With code below I have the button changing appearance/color but not the icon. The icon is nested within the button element like so:

```
<td key={i}>
  <button 
    onClick={this.schedulerTableTimeChange}
    className="waves-effect waves-light btn"
  >
    <i className="material-icons">check_box</i>
  </button>
</td>
```

So can get the whole element with `item.target` and change the color with `item.target.className = x` but I also want to change the child element of the nested `<i>child</i>` as well to change the icon. How can I do this?

Here is my entire onClick:

```
schedulerTableTimeChange(item){
  const green = 'waves-effect waves-light btn';
  const red = 'waves-effect waves-light red btn';

  if(item.target.className === red){
    item.target.className = green
    //change <i> child here here
  }else if(item.target.className === green){
    item.target.className = red
    //change <i> child here here
  }
}
```

also using `materialize-css` which accounts for the color and icon changes based on `className`

Comment: That's not a particularly reacty way of doing things. Better to make a button component...

Comment: I thought about doing that too but when I made a whole new button and returned it in the onClick i didn't get any changes. Could you post code on how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a Button component, something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Button extends Component {

  state = { checked: false };

  clickHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    if (this.props.onClick) {
      this.props.onClick(e);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const green = "waves-effect waves-light btn";
    const red = "waves-effect waves-light red btn";
    return (
      <button onClick={this.clickHandler} className={checked ? green : red}>
        <i className="material-icons">
          {checked ? "check_box" : "somethingelse"}
        </i>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

Of course change `somethingelse` to the correct icon name... [Here's a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7t8ixi?file=index.js)

HTH
-Ted

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question but I upvoted it because it did lead me to a solution. I was initially hesitant because of how the state of the class was already set up but this works great. Thanks!